# Download a File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, download

I am implementing Download Manager using Javascript. I want to know How can I download a file from server using Javascript. Where Javascript will connect to server , Download a file and save it on local file system.

Kindly Help me out here , with all possibilities.

Regards,
Brijesh Thakur

Answer (score 1):

You can download data, but you can't save anything to the local file system with javascript. This is impossible.

Comment: Can you please point me to some example. Because I am completely new to Javascript.

Comment: Example of what?  What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: Example for Download a file :) and where can I save the file or downloaded data will be in memory only?. How our standard browsers(Mozila ,IE , Chrome) are achieving of downloading files and saving to our Hard Drive ?. Please put some light on above questions.